# How to create a Dictionary with any types in Type variables?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, types, dictionary

Currently im facing the problem I need to create an instance of Dictionary with any type of its cases. The types are delivered by the arguments of the method. 
I do not simply want to create a dynamic or object type Dictionary, because this faces the user alot of convertion problems by using my library. 
I also cannot use a simple constructor, because my method fills the Dictionary with data (that is stored in a file) in real. It's important to create the specific dictionary by Type variables.
This is what im thinking of:

```
public static Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> createDict(Type type1, Type type2)
{
    // how to create the dictionary?
    // im filling my dictionary with any data ...
    return dict;
}
```

Here the user calls my method:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = MyLib.createDict(typeof(string), typeof(int));
// or
MyOwnType myInstance = new MyOwnType();
Dictionary<string, MyOwnType> dict = MyLib.createDict(typeof(string), myInstance.GetType());
```

Comment: And what is your exact problem? And why don't you use generic arguments for your function call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Type dictType = typeof(Dictionary<, >).MakeGenericType(Type1, Type2);
var dict = Activator.CreateInstance(dictType);
```

- Get the Type for `Dictionary`
- Create a generic type with the specified Types using `MakeGenericType`
- Create an instance of the generic type using `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: oh so simple, i tried this with the target type first, but var seems to be working finally. However, i realized it with dynamic to be able to call my Dictionary methods to fill my dictionary. Thank you.

Comment: How do you `Add` items to the newly created Dictionary? `dict.Add("keyName", "value")`  won't compile because `dict` is recognized as just a general `object`.

Answer (score 4):

Using Generics you can do the following:

```
public static Dictionary<T, U> CreateDict<T,U>()
{
    Dictionary<T,U> dict = new Dictionary<T,U>();

    // Fill dictionary with data     

    return dict;
}
```

The user then can call this function:

```
var myDict1 = CreateDict<string,int>();
var myDict2 = CreateDict<string,MyOwnType>();
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is just, it can be any type, even instances of own types by the user itself. I am confused how to create the dictionary dynamically in that case.

Comment: The user will supply the types. In the example you give, the user is passing a string and int as parameters. It doesn't matter if these are custom types or not. I will edit my answer with an example

Comment: i updated my first post with an example, thank you.

Comment: thanks for your effort, however, in my library i cannot use this by several reasons. However i learned alot from it, thank you very much.

Comment: My current (just finished) project is a serializer that even works with dictionaries. The problem appeared on my deserializeDict method. The user calls the method with the XML file path and the type of the dictionary, i get the child types by GetGenericArguments(). So i got the types in Type variables before i create the dictionary. Its alot of easier for the user just transmit the type of the Dictionary instead of both child types like on your way. However, thx.